# Remove the auto-generated marks from dired buffer

Tags: dired, debugging

Upon invoking dired with C-x d, it display

[image]

Five of the files have already been marked automatically ,

Consult with the manual of [operation on files](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/emacs.html#Operating-on-Files)

Strik U and * u to remove the mark but failed.

How could remove the auto-generated marks

BTW, what's ?? mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you see this if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q`? If not then bisect your init file to find the culprit.

That should always be the first step when trying to investigate some problem or something you wonder about: find out whether the problem comes from Emacs or yourself -- i.e., code that you have, one way or another, added to Emacs.

I think you are using some code (other than what comes with `emacs -Q`) that does this. Vanilla Emacs (`emacs -Q`) does not do it. For one thing, there is no predefined mark `M`. Likewise, there is no predefined `??`. And that's really both a `?` mark, in the mark position, plus a second `?` after that position.

To remove the marks (however they were created), did you try `M-DEL` (`<M-backspace>`) followed by `RET`? That's command `dired-unmark-all-files`, and a simple `RET` at the prompt removes *all* marks, of any kind. That should include the mysterious `M` marks.